# PM2 not running child processes in cluster mode

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to integrate PM2 module in my node application and created ecosystem file named 'processes.js' which includes code :

```
    apps : [ {
        name: "server",
        script : "server.js",
        instances : 1,
        exec_mode : "cluster",
        autorestart : true,
        env : {
            "NODE_ENV" : "dev"
        },
        env_cluster : {
            "NODE_ENV" : "cluster"
        },
        env_staging : {
            "NODE_ENV" : "staging"
        },
        env_prod : {
            "NODE_ENV" : "prod"
        }
    } ]
};
```

when I run **pm2 start processes.js --env dev** then only daemon process gets online. No child process is present.

Comment: Just start with `pm2 start processes.js --env dev -i max` more could be found here http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: @Grynets -i is used to define number of instances to run but that I have already defined in processes.js file. Command you mentioned runs two daemon processes named "processes".